# Get the content of one article

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to get the content of one article in my template "article.php" in my blog. How can I complete this PHP code to display the content of my article (without a loop)?

```
<?php

try
{       
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=devoir-nabila;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{       
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}    

$numeroArticle = $_GET['numero-article'];    

$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = \'$numeroArticle\'");
$donnees = $req->fetch();    

// here, I want to display my content in my HTML     

?>
```

Comment: Add the HTML for you article page and echo the article data from `$donnnees` wherever you want that in the HTML...?

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to generate a string using HTML tags
and output them using the `echo`.

For example:

If database schema is

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `publ_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `content`,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

After execute: `$donnees = $req->fetch();`

`$donnees` - [will contains an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

In this way:

```
$title     = $donnees[    'title'];
$publ_data = $donnees['publ_data'];
$content   = $donnees[  'content'];
```

Then you can display them as follows:

```
$str = "<h2>Title: "     . $title     . "</h2>" .
       "<pre>Publ at: "  . $publ_date . "</pre>".
       "<div>Content: "  . $content   . "</div>";

echo $str;
```

Of course, this solution is applicable only for very simple tasks.

Comment: Please write in English.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not the downvoter, but I think you should explain out the get the data (ex `$title`) from `$donnees`.

Comment: Thank for you recomendation.